# Call C++ function from Python by reference

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have successfully wrapped my C++ code with SWIG and it loads fine into Python. I am using the [Olena library for image processing](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Olena/).

However, I don't know how to call my functions that require a pointer to an image!

For instance, my function for eroding an image is prototyped as follows:

```
mln::image2d<mln::value::int_u8> imErossion(
    const mln::image2d<mln::value::int_u8> *img, int size, int nbh
);
```

Result of running my code within Python:

```
    from swilena import *
    from algol import *

    image = image2d_int_u8
    ima = image.load("micro24_20060309_grad_mod.pgm")

    eroded_ima = imErossion(ima,1,8) 
    >>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: in method 'imErossion', argument 1 of type 
       'mln::image2d<mln::value::int_u8 > const *'
```

I have been looking all around the web to try and solve this myself, but it turns to be harder than I expected.

I'm not sure how to pass a pointer from Python -- the equivalent of this C++ code:

```
eroded_ima = imErossion(&ima,1,8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked with my professor at university, and we decided it would be better to implemente a function that would return the pointer to the image when this one was loaded and declared it global:

```
mln::image2d<mln::value::int_u8> working_img;

mln::image2d<mln::value::int_u8> *imLoad(const std::string path){
    mln::io::pgm::load(working_img, path);
    return &working_img;
}

void imSave(const std::string path){

    mln::io::pgm::save(working_img, path);

}
```

What do you think about this?

Comment: I wrote a C++ binding library called LikeMagic that is for a similar purpose as SWIG.  I can't say whether how you're doing it is best practice but the solution you propose in this answer is one I've done and haven't personally run into problems with it yet.  I wrote LikeMagic to automatically handle most type conversion cases, but there are also case where it was inconvenient to make the library handle it and then I just write a helper function in C++.

Comment: This program is going to be used for several users through an apache server with an html front end, but I think as we are creating a new process for each request, it might be okay to have a global variable define and I shouldn't worry about "true-concurrency"